# How to use two angular pickadate calender control in single HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

```
I want to use two angular pickadate control in same page.
```

https://github.com/restorando/angular-pickadate

I tried the code like this,

```
angular.module('datesample', ['pickadate']).

controller('pickadateCtrl', ['$scope', 'dateFilter', 
                          function ($scope, dateFilter) {
    $scope.date = dateFilter(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'); 
    $scope.minDate = '1950-01-01';
    $scope.maxDate = '2114-03-18';
}]);

<div pickadate ng-model="date" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate"></div>

<div pickadate ng-model="date" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate"></div>
```

but, its not working. How to make correct this code to work? here one problem is, surely want to give `ng-model="date"` then only the calender selection will be working correctly. please i am struggling

Comment: you should have 2 separate properties for each.

Comment: i'm new to angularjs. please how to make 2 properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for this question.

if we want use two angularjs **pickadate** calender control in same page, want to write a different controllers

**JS:**

```
angular.module('datesample', ['pickadate']);

.controller('pickadateCtrl1', ['$scope', 'dateFilter', 
                 function ($scope, dateFilter) {
    $scope.date = dateFilter(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');     
    $scope.minDate = '1990-01-01';
    $scope.maxDate = '2020-12-31';
}])

.controller('pickadateCtrl2', ['$scope', 'dateFilter', 
              function ($scope, dateFilter) {
    $scope.date = dateFilter(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');     
    $scope.minDate = '1990-01-01';
    $scope.maxDate = '2020-12-31';
}]);
```

**HTML:**

```
     <div>
          <div ng-controller="pickadateCtrl1">
               <h5>From Date</h5>
               <div pickadate id="date1" ng-model="date" min-date="minDate"   
                   max-date="maxDate"></div>                       
          </div>

           <div ng-controller="pickadateCtrl2">
               <h5>To Date</h5>
               <div pickadate id="date2" ng-model="date" min-date="minDate"   
                   max-date="maxDate"></div>                       
           </div>                    
       </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm imaging that you need actually 2 properties.

```
angular.module('datesample', ['pickadate']);

controller('pickadateCtrl', ['$scope', 'dateFilter', function ($scope, dateFilter) {
    $scope.date1 = dateFilter(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'); 
    $scope.date2 = dateFilter(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'); 
    $scope.minDate = '1950-01-01';
    $scope.maxDate = '2114-03-18';
}]);

<div pickadate ng-model="date1" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate"></div>

<div pickadate ng-model="date2" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate"></div>
```

Comment: i'm said na `ng-model="date"` then only calender selection will be working otherwise not working....please see demo https://github.com/restorando/angular-pickadate